# get multiple columns of different table in function by using joins in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Here is the example with table with table name 'company'

```
id     name          age         address
1      Paul          32          California
```

Ans second table name "department"

```
id     dept_name       dept_id 
1      engineering       5
```

---

From the above table if I do joins by combining id column and retrieving the fields as name, age,,address,dept.

Here wat I did is:-

```
create type tmp_comp as(name text,age integer, address character, dept character);

create or replace function comp_detail (in_id integer)
returns tmp_comp as
$$

declare 
out_put tmp_comp%rowtype;

begin
select name, age, address,dept from company as c inner join department as d on c.id=d.id where c.id=in_id;
return out_put;
end;$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

---

If I execute this it'll run success.

but if I want to call the function, it ll show error...

```
select * from comp_detail(1)


ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function comp_detail(integer) line 7 at SQL statement
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RETURN QUERY` to return a `SETOF A_TYPE` as described [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html)

```
create or replace function comp_detail (in_id integer) returns setof tmp_comp as $$

declare out_put tmp_comp%rowtype;

begin 
    return query(select name, age, address,dept from company as c inner join department as d on c.id=d.id where c.id=in_id);
end;$$

LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

And you can call your function as follow:

```
select * from comp_detail (1);
```

Comment: Thank you brother, it runs successfully. Brother one request. Can you just share you mail_id, so that If I have droughts I can send you a request. please. You can share through by test mail. My mail_id is suchithshivali@gmail.com

Comment: Hi @suchithshivali If that was what you were lokking for, so please                `accept` my answer. And it is a bad idea to ask for somone's email,  because you don't need it, you can ask here on SO and lot of people can help you (better than one) :)

Comment: Okay sorry. Thank you.